403 Forbidden error when uploading files from Postman to PHP API
I am trying to upload files from Postman using PHP API. I'm getting a 403 forbidden error:
<html>

<head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1>403 Forbidden</h1>
    </center>
</body>

</html>

Update #2
Update #3
These are the contents of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being viewed by Web clients.
<FilesMatch "^.ht">
Require all denied



can you share more background to your PHP? do you use a framework? what is your environment (dev or production) and so on.

The key was to Override to allow the AWS-AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet rule in AWS WAF for the ALB (application load balancer). Once this rule was overridden, the file upload worked fine!


Check Server Permissions
chmod -R 755 /path/to/upload/directory
chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/upload/directory

Check .htaccess rules: Check if there are Deny from all

File upload size limit: on file "php.ini"
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M



Thank you for that! I've done all of the above - same 403 error:

header("Acess-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
//header("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
header("Content-Type: multipart/form-data");
header("Acess-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Acess-Control-Allow-Headers: Acess-Control-Allow-Headers,Content-Type,Acess-Control-Allow-Methods, Authorization");

$fileName  =  $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tempPath  =  $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize  =  $_FILES['file']['size'];
$fileError =  $_FILES['file']['error'];````

By the way I have updated this php.ini file:
/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini

I am looking at /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


This is not php issue, I think this is apache configuration,
Can you try to set this
" SecFilterEngine Off ", That turned off the mod_security filter in general.

Getting this now:
apache2 -S
[Mon Sep 02 20:30:05.020758 2024] [core:warn] [pid 941911] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined

Went to /etc/apache2/envvars:
export APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX

I've turned SecFilter* off:
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>````

It's very interesting - all other POST with other fields are going through perfect! It's only with the file uploads, its all failing.

The 403 error is deeper, it's coming from the AWS load balancer, with WAF (web application firewall) enabled. There are no apache2 logs with 403 error.
